# Trespass to Chattel: possessor suing for bodily harm

Tags: united-states, tort

X performs trespass to Y's chattel. X endures bodily harm as a result of possessing Y's chattel. Can X recover for bodily harm?

My goal is to know whether there are **any** scenarios that fall within the skeleton of the above hypo in which X can recover for bodily harm **resulting from his possession of the chattel**. Please note that conversion is not synonymous with trespass to chattel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Consider a hire car contract where the hirer exceeds the terms of the contract by extending the term of the rental. If a fault in the car caused personal injury (say a faulty airbag), the hirer would have a claim in negligence and possibly under contract.